# JFreeChart 1.09 renders JPG charts with whole background in RED (or pink)

Tags: jsf, charts, seam, jfreechart

i'm stuck with this problem, JFreeChart 1.09 renders JPG charts with whole background in RED (or pink). I'm using JFreeChart not directly, but over Seam JSF taglibs, the components: **linechart** and **barchart**. They both work fine, only that the rendered JPG images have an light-red overlayer background.

Is it correct so? or im missing something?

Thank you very much!

Comment: i just want chart with withe background, but the rendered images all have light-red background. Very annoying.

Answer (score 5):

Exact same issue: red/pink background on JPEG rendering. PNG was fine.
I have tried with a few different versions of jfreechart and jcommon without any luck.

I have finally solved the issue by using an imageType parameter set to RGB when creating the buffered image.

I had this code:

```
BufferedImage buf = chart.createBufferedImage(320, 200, null);
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
ChartUtilities.writeBufferedImageAsJPEG(response.getOutputStream(), 0.75f, buf);
```

I have solved by adding a BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB parameter on the 1st line:

```
BufferedImage buf = chart.createBufferedImage(320, 200, 
                             BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the buggy version 1.09 of jfreechart, together with jcommon-1.012.jar automatica downloaded per Maven. As fas as i replaced them with the JAR from Seam 2.2.0.GA distribution, they worked fine. And now i can save ans show the rendered images without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the background color on your Plot object, something like:

```
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: It could also be on the chart as far as I remember. Try `chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE)` if the plot background is not enough.

Comment: plotBackgroundPaint="white" is already set on the jsf component linechart. But it didn't help. As i said obove, im not using JFreeChart direckty, but over the JSF components. They all work fine, except this problem.

Comment: When i try i save the rendered JPG images from browser and show them with photo-viewer programm (windows paint, office picture manager) then the programs say, that the images are defect or format not supported, cant be shown. But on browser they are displayed.

Comment: what os are you running on? I came across this pink background before but think now maybe it only happened when running on an AIX box whereas on Windows it was fine. Could be related to the default colors for the UIManager